# Why won't my code apply the program to each cell? Using For Each cell and If

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, foreach

My newfound issue is that the data from the new sheet is copied, at range G8:G22, and pasted in a new sheet, at range J8:J22, but it will only read cell J8 and copy the code to the entire column, thus replacing the values already in that column because J8 is blank.
Yet, the idea was that this code was suppose to have it go down a column and check each cell, only to paste the copied range from the copied sheet into the selected range of the paste sheet if there were no values found. But if there was a single cell with a value in it, then it would offset to the next column to the right and paste the data in that column.

```
Sub IMS1CopyToNextColumn()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("SEEBREZ IMS.1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("IMS.1")

    copySheet.Range("G8:G22").Copy

    For Each cell In pasteSheet.Range("J8:J22")
        If cell.Value = "" Then
           pasteSheet.Range("J8:J22").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       ElseIf cell.Value > 0 Then
            pasteSheet.Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next cell

    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Single Column Range To First Blank/Empty Column Range

**Blank**

```vb
Sub IMS1ToNextBlankColumn()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("SEEBREZ IMS.1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("G8:G22")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("IMS.1")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("J8")
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(rCount)
    
    Do Until Application.CountBlank(drg) = rCount
        Set drg = drg.Offset(, 1)
    Loop
 
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
End Sub
```

**Empty**

```vb
Sub IMS1ToNextEmptyColumn()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("SEEBREZ IMS.1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("G8:G22")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("IMS.1")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("J8")
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count)
    
    Do Until Application.CountA(drg) = 0
        Set drg = drg.Offset(, 1)
    Loop
 
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
End Sub
```

**Empty: Using the Find Method**

- To avoid the loop, you can simply use the Find Method.
- The following copies the values to the first (left-most) column whose rows from 8 to 22 are empty.

```vb
Sub IMS1ToNextEmptyColumnFind()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("SEEBREZ IMS.1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("G8:G22")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("IMS.1")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("J8")
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count)
    
    With drg
        Dim dlCell As Range: Set dlCell = .Resize(, dws.Columns.Count _
            - .Column + 1).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        If Not dlCell Is Nothing Then
            Set drg = .Offset(, dlCell.Column - .Column + 1)
        End If
    End With
    
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
End Sub
```

[image]